# Partial derivatives of a certain function

Tags: real-analysis, multivariable-calculus, derivatives

I am given a function $f: \mathbb{R}^2 \rightarrow \mathbb{R}, f(x,y) = \frac{y\sin x - x\sin y}{x^2+y^2}$ if $(x,y) \not= (0,0)$ and $f(0,0) = 0$. I have proved that it is continuous and that it is $C^1$. However, I am asked to show that $\frac{\partial^2 f}{\partial x \partial y} \not= \frac{\partial^2 f}{\partial y \partial x}$. I know that each partial derivative of first order goes to $0$ if $(x,y) \rightarrow 0$, but whenever I try to figure out the second derivative using the definition, both derivatives in the text above are $0$. I would like to know where I am wrong.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You have$$\frac{\partial f}{\partial x}(x,y)=\begin{cases}\dfrac{y \left(x^2+y^2\right)\cos(x)-2xy\sin(x)+\left(x^2-y^2\right)\sin(y)}{\left(x^2+y^2\right)^2}&\text{ if }(x,y)\ne(0,0)\\0&\text{ if }(x,y)=(0,0),\end{cases}$$and therefore\begin{align}\frac{\partial^2f}{\partial y\partial x}(0,0)&=\lim_{y\to0}\frac{\frac{\partial f}{\partial x}(0,y)-\frac{\partial f}{\partial x}(0,0)}y\\&=\lim_{y\to0}\frac{y^3-y^2 \sin (y)}{y^5}\\&=\frac16.\end{align}But a similar computation shows that$$\frac{\partial^2f}{\partial x\partial y}(0,0)=-\frac16\ne\frac{\partial^2f}{\partial y\partial x}(0,0).$$

Comment: Ok, therefore my mistake was only on the definition of partial derivative. Thanks for your answer

Comment: I'm glad I could help.